# Getting web page in response of XMLRPC Request in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, xml-rpc

I had downloaded https://github.com/corristo/xmlrpc and i followed instruction but i got a webpage in response

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.xyz.com/xmlrpc"];
XMLRPCRequest *request = [[XMLRPCRequest alloc] initWithURL: URL];
XMLRPCConnectionManager *manager = [XMLRPCConnectionManager sharedManager];
[request setMethod: @"login" withParameter:@[@usename,@password]];
[manager spawnConnectionWithXMLRPCRequest:request delegate:self];
[request release];
```

and for response

```
- (void)request:(XMLRPCRequest *)request didReceiveResponse: (XMLRPCResponse *)response {
    if ([response isFault]) {
        NSLog(@"Fault code: %@", [response faultCode]);

        NSLog(@"Fault string: %@", [response faultString]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Parsed response: %@", [response object]);
    }

    NSLog(@"Response body: %@", [response body]);
}
```

but i got a webpage in response instead of a string.

Comment: Well, what does the web page contain? What kind of a resource are you calling?

Comment: i give webservice call to magento  with username and password in xml request format contains in login method at remote end.

Comment: So you're getting a HTML login form from Magento? That sounds like something's set up the wrong way there, no?

Comment: ya..  but i cant understand what is wrong because i followed  https://github.com/corristo/xmlrpc  then also it returns such thing in response...

Comment: The very first question is what the Magento page is returning to you, and if it's the wrong thing, why that happens. That part probably doesn't have much to do with the client code you are using to connect to the Magento install.

Comment: my issue is solved.. there are problem in parameter passing to the xmlrpc request.. Now i got proper response by passing proper array to the login method mentioned in my code..  and thanks for helping me..